# UML: additional properties of model attributes

Tags: uml, enterprise-architect

I'm using Enterprise Architect 10.

I need to define additional properties of model attributes, example: show condition (text), edit condition (text), location in data tree from remote source (text) and others. Those properties are for documentation purposes at the moment. But it may occur that some of those properties will be used during generating source code by custom generator.

Answer (score 3):

Use tagged values for this purpose. Creating Advanced/Properties is not really possible. Tagged values can be shown in compartments if you switch that on in the Feature and Compartment Visibility. Shape scripts can use them to render individual shapes and the code generator can also evaluate them.

As Geert points out, start looking into MDG creation. Though it's quite some start-up you have to do, it will pay off in rather short terms.

Comment: Thomas is correct. I would like to add that in order to do it properly you should look into creating a UML profile with stereotypes that define which tagged values you need for which type of (meta) element. It may seem a lot of work in the beginning, but it will definitely pay off in the long run.  

PS. And you should upgrade too. There's lots interesting new features and enhancements in v12.1 compared to v10.

Comment: What's "MDG" stand for?

Comment: @JimL. It stands for Model Driven Generator (IIRC) and is a way to bundle profiles and add-ins for Enterprise Architect. A bit tricky (like almost anything in EA) but also very powerful.

Comment: Minor point: it's Model Driven Generation, not generator. Major point: Add-Ins are not bundled into MDG Technologies. They are a different type of adaptation, and consist of a DLL with code that does stuff (typically in response to events fired by EA), while an MDG Technology is an XML file with configuration data.

Comment: @Uffe Don't be too picky. Yes, they are not bundled, but they go hand in hand - the EA way...